# How to mock a service class calling Rest API and getting ResponseEntity as Response

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, mockito

I have below classes.

```
@Service
class RestService {
@Autowired
private RestTemplate restTemplate;

public ResponseEntity<String> callService(String param) {
return restTemplate.exchange(....);
}
}
```

---

```
@Service
class CallingService{
@Autowired
private RestService restService;

public ResponseDTO getResponse(String param) {
ResponseEntity<String> response = restService.callService(param);
ResponseDTO responseDTO = convert(response)// JSON Convertor here
return responseDTO;
}
}
```

---

Now I want to write test class for CallingService class.

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertNotNull;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertNull;
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertThrows;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.doNothing;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.doThrow;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.times;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.verify;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.xml.datatype.DatatypeConfigurationException;

import org.apache.cxf.helpers.IOUtils;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Rule;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.rules.ExpectedException;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.Mockito;
import org.mockito.MockitoAnnotations;
import org.mockito.junit.MockitoJUnitRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;

@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
class CallingServiceTest{
@InjectMocks
private CallingService service;
@Mock
private RestService restService;

@Test
public testGetResponse(){
ResponseDTO dto = createDummyObject();

HttpHeaders header = new HttpHeaders();
header.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);

ResponseEntity<String> responseEntity = new ResponseEntity<>("response message", header, 
HttpStatus.OK);

when(restService.callService(Mockito.anyString())).thenReturn(responseEntity);
// mocking converter here
 dto = service.getResponse("param");
//assert conditions here onwards
}
}
```

---

The invocation at line service.getResponse("param") gives NullPointerException. On debugging I found that response received in CallingService.getResponse() is null (i.e. restService.callService(param) returned null) and hence code broken into convert() method.

I tried with a lot of code manipulations but no luck. Hope anyone might have answer for this.

Comment: Could you please share your imports from the test class as well?

Comment: @SSK Edited the class with the Junit imports.

Comment: You are are using the combination of `Junit4` and `Junit5`. I have added my answer below. Hope that will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found a workaround by combining flavours of above two answers.

```
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.*;

import org.apache.cxf.helpers.IOUtils;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Rule;
import org.junit.
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.rules.ExpectedException;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.Mockito;
import org.mockito.MockitoAnnotations;
import org.mockito.junit.MockitoJUnitRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;

@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class CallingServiceTest{
@InjectMocks
private CallingService service;
@Mock
private RestService restService;
@BeforeEach
public void setup(){
MockitoAnnotations.init(this);
}

@Test
public testGetResponse(){
ResponseDTO dto = createDummyObject();

HttpHeaders header = new HttpHeaders();
header.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);

ResponseEntity<String> responseEntity = new ResponseEntity<>   ("response message", header, HttpStatus.OK);

     when(restService.callService(Mockito.anyString())).thenReturn(responseEntity);
// mocking converter here
dto = service.getResponse("param");
//assert conditions here onwards
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use both `@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)` and `@SpringBootTest`. They're both setting up JUnit Rules and you can only have one rule active.

You need to use Spring annotations. Instead of `@Mock` use `@MockBean` so Spring can properly inject it to the service.

```
@SpringBootTest
class CallingServiceTest{
@Autowired
private CallingService service;
@MockBean
private RestService restService;

@Test
public testGetResponse(){
ResponseDTO dto = createDummyObject();

HttpHeaders header = new HttpHeaders();
header.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);

ResponseEntity<String> responseEntity = new ResponseEntity<>("response message", header, 
HttpStatus.OK);

when(restService.callService(Mockito.anyString())).thenReturn(responseEntity);
// mocking converter here
 dto = service.getResponse("param");
//assert conditions here onwards
}
}
```

Alternatively, you can use just Mockito since you don't really need to initialize SpringContext for this test I think.

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
class CallingServiceTest{
@InjectMocks
private CallingService service;
@Mock
private RestService restService;

@Test
public testGetResponse(){
ResponseDTO dto = createDummyObject();

HttpHeaders header = new HttpHeaders();
header.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);

ResponseEntity<String> responseEntity = new ResponseEntity<>("response message", header, 
HttpStatus.OK);

when(restService.callService(Mockito.anyString())).thenReturn(responseEntity);
// mocking converter here
 dto = service.getResponse("param");
//assert conditions here onwards
}
}
```

Comment: Only using @RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class) gives null value of restService. Its not mocking the bean.

Comment: Where exactly? In the test or in `CallingService`?

Comment: In the test class CallingServiceTest.

Comment: Can you try calling `MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(CallingServiceTest.class)`? In a `@Before` method. `MockitoJUnitRunner` should already be handling the annotations though.

Comment: same thing as before. null value of restService.

Comment: This issue coming for the only methods which are calling restService. Other test methods are working fine with my current code configuration.

Comment: Well, you done messed up. Post your changes and error..

Comment: kept RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
    and added  
    before
    void setup() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(CallingServiceTest.class);
    }
    // rest all is same 




java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.junit.platform.commons.support.AnnotationSupport.findAnnotation(Ljava/util/Optional;Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljava/util/Optional;
 at org.mockito.junit.jupiter.MockitoExtension.retrieveAnnotationFromTestClasses(MockitoExtension.java:183)

Comment: Are you using JUnit4 or JUnit5? jupiter is JUnit5

Comment: Spring 5 is using JUnit5 by default.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your import you are using a combination of `Junit4` and `Junit5`.
This will not work properly.

Steps to run with `Junit5`

1. Change your imports to `org.junit.jupiter.api.*`
2. Change `@Before` to `@BeforeEach`.
3. Remove `@SpringBootTest` not required with `Junit5`
4. Change `@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)` to `@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)`

Please find the changed code below

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
class CallingServiceTest{
@InjectMocks
private CallingService service;
@Mock
private RestService restService;

@Test
public testGetResponse(){
ResponseDTO dto = createDummyObject();

HttpHeaders header = new HttpHeaders();
header.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);

ResponseEntity<String> responseEntity = new ResponseEntity<>("response message", header, 
HttpStatus.OK);

when(restService.callService(Mockito.anyString())).thenReturn(responseEntity);
// mocking converter here
 dto = service.getResponse("param");
//assert conditions here onwards
}
}
```

If you want to run with `Junit4` change your import for `@Test` to `import org.junit.Test` from `import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test`

Either one of the solutions will work.

Comment: Using settings for Junit5 gives below error.

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.junit.platform.commons.support.AnnotationSupport.findAnnotation(Ljava/util/Optional;Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljava/util/Optional;
 at org.mockito.junit.jupiter.MockitoExtension.retrieveAnnotationFromTestClasses(MockitoExtension.java:183)

Comment: If you got that error just run your test cases with `JUnit 4`. Right-click on test class -> run as -> run configuration -> select JUnit 4

Comment: Actually I want to run the tests with Junit5 only. The same code configuration works fine for other test classes which are not having restService.

Comment: Every method call is mocked perfectly except the response of restService.callService()